# E-mail address that include a specific tenant domain name

Tags: powershell, office365, export-to-csv

I want to get users where the ProxyAddress has upper case SMTP domain.onmicrosoft.com and/or domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com formatted.

Error message :

```
At line:1 char:218
+ ... pression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.Licenses))} -ExpandProperty Proxyad ...
+                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-ExpandProperty' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:234
+ ... ng]::join(“;”, ($_.Licenses))} -ExpandProperty Proxyaddresses | ? {$_ ...
+                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'Proxyaddresses' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:233
+ ... pression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.Licenses))} -ExpandProperty Proxyad ...
+                                                                  ~
The hash literal was incomplete.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

I have tried like below :

```
Get-MSOLUser -All | Where-Object {$_.IsLicensed -eq $true -and $_.BlockCredential -eq $false} | Select-Object  FirstName, LastName, UserPrincipalName, @{Name=’Licenses’;Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.Licenses))} -Expand Proxyaddresses | ? {$_ -cmatch '^SMTP\:.*@domain.onmicrosoft.com'} | Export-Csv C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Userlist.csv
```

Update :

```
#TYPE System.String
"FirstName","LastName","UserPrincipalName","Licenses","Length"
"mailbox2",,"mailbox2@domain.onmicrosoft.com","Microsoft.Online.Administration.UserLicense","48"
```

Comment: Did you ever get things working?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a } in the code, just right after {[string]::join(';', ($_.Licenses))} **}**

I would recommend that you use VS code and have an extension to color your different parenteses and brackets.

```
Get-MSOLUser -All | Where-Object {$_.IsLicensed -eq $true -and $_.BlockCredential -eq $false} | Select-Object  FirstName, LastName, UserPrincipalName, @{Name='Licenses';Expression={[string]::join(';', ($_.Licenses))}} -Expand Proxyaddresses | ? {$_ -cmatch '^SMTP\:.*@domain.onmicrosoft.com'} | Export-Csv C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Userlist.csv
```

Comment: Thanks But I am not able to get licence information. I have updated my answer.